# How can I "retry" a try-catch?

Tags: java, exception

In my code, I will attempt a certain task in a try-block. If exceptions are thrown, the catch-blocks will rectify the errors encountered (usually prompting for correct input). After that, the program is supposed to try again repeatedly until success is achieved. My current code is as follows:

```
for (bool isSuccess = false; !isSuccess;) {
    try {
        ...
        isSuccess = true;
    }
    // catch blocks here to correct any exceptions thrown
}
```

As can be seen, I'm currently using a loop structure to make the try-catch block start over if the try block fail, until the try block succeeds completely. Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: A while loop could do

Comment: I don't see anything so wrong with your approach.  Why do you want to change it?

Comment: Personally I'd use a `break` statement to terminate the loop, but one way or another, if you want to repeat the same action (e.g., prompting for input), you'll need a loop (or recursion of course, but I personally wouldn't).

Comment: Just checking whether there's a better way out there, I'm sure what I'm trying to do with my try block is a common thing.

Comment: It isn't in the general case. When an exception happens, 99/100 times it is unrecoverable and you just want to let the exception bubble up to the point where it is logged and the application or thread is interrupted. Your case, reading input presumably from the keyboard, is one of the exceptional cases where you need it. I can assure you that in real applications you won't be writing code to read keyboard input very often.

Answer (score 12):

I'd prefer to see a `do` loop that exits by default (then there is less chance of encountering an infinite loop). Your use of the `boolean` type only really mimics the behaviour of `break` and `continue`. As an alternative, perhaps more natural way, consider

```
do {
    try {
        // some code 
    } catch (/*whatever*/){
        continue; // go again
    }
    break;
} while (true);
```

Comment: The `false` flag means continue won't work. After it reaches there, the condition is checked and control exits.

Comment: You're right But what I am telling is that rather then re-trying, or `continue`ing at the start of loop when some exception occurs, control will rather exit and thats not the intention.

Comment: `int i = 5;
        do {
            if (i <= 0)
                throw new RuntimeException();
            i--;
            System.out.println(i);
            continue;

        } while (false);` Execute this

Comment: @xploreraj; You’re correct (as you know!). Finally got round to fixing this. Apologies.

Answer (score 4):

Just to give you an alternative, and if your code allows you to do so, then you could also use recursion. But in my eyes this is less favorable compared to the other ways to solve this.

```
public void doSomething() {
    try {
       ...
    } catch(Exception e) {
       doSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use a while loop.

```
while(!isSuccess){
    try{
        //DO Stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define a maximum of attempts. Otherwise in a worst scenario when all failures occur you app will be frozen.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `while` loop

```
boolean isSuccess = false;
while(!isSuccess) { // loop till to isSuccess become true
    try {
        ....
        isSuccess = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Some Exception accrued, you can have 2 options
        // 1. break the loop with break;
        // 2. continue the process
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use recursion to do this. But I don't think it would be efficient. Do ... while would be the best approach.